# Calculate the normal curvature of $\alpha : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R^3$, $\alpha(t) := (\cos t, \sin t, t)$. Is it a geodesic?

Tags: solution-verification, surfaces

I have the following exercise and some hesitation.

**(Exercise)** Consider the curve $\alpha : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R^3$, $\alpha(t) := (\cos t, \sin t, t)$ and the elementary surface $x : \mathbb R \times (0, +\infty) \to \mathbb R ^3$, $x(u, v) := (u \cos v, u \sin v, 1+v-u)$.

**(1)** Verify that the trace of $\alpha$ is contained in that one of $x$.

**(2)** Calculate the normal curvature of $\alpha$. Determine whether $\alpha$ is a geodesic.

Here is my attempt.

Looking a bit at how the curve and surface are defined, I can tell that $\alpha = x (1, \cdot)$, but they do not *typecheck*. It could be an oversight, it could be $\alpha : (0, +\infty) \to \mathbb R^3$ or $x : (0, +\infty) \times \mathbb R \to \mathbb R^3$...

**(1)** From the identity just mentioned, it is immediate.

**(2)** Since the curve is contained in the surface, you can write $\alpha(t) = x(u(t), v(t))$, where in our case $u(t) = 1$ and $v(t) = t$. In this case, $$\alpha'(t) = x_v(1, t)$$ and thus in the basis $\left\{ x_u(u, v), x_v(u, v) \right\}$ of the tangent space in $x(u, v)$ it has coordinates $(u', v') = (0, 1)$. The normal curvature is, by definition, $$k_n(t) = \frac{\mathrm{II}(\alpha'(t), \alpha'(t))}{\mathrm I (\alpha'(t), \alpha'(t))}$$ with $\mathrm I$ and $\mathrm{II}$ the two fundamental forms of the surface. It doesn't seem to me that there is the need to compute the whole thing: $$\mathrm I(\alpha'(t), \alpha'(t)) = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} E & F \\ F & G \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} = G.$$ Similarly for the second fundamental form: $$\mathrm{II}(\alpha'(t), \alpha'(t)) = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} e & f \\ f & g \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} = g .$$ Here, $E$, $F$, $G$, $e$, $f$ and $g$ are functions in $(u, v)$ and $u$ and $v$ are functions in $t$, but notation gets heavy to write down... All right, now some preliminary calculations:
\begin{align*}
& x_u = (\cos v, \sin v, -1) \\
& x_v = (-u \sin v, u \cos v, 1) \\
& x_u \wedge x_v = (\sin v + u \cos v, -\cos v + u \sin v, u) \\
& \lVert x_u \wedge x_v \rVert = \sqrt{1+2u^2} \\
& x_{vv} = -u (\cos v, \sin v, 0)
\end{align*}
Finally:
\begin{align*}
& G = \langle x_v, x_v \rangle = u^2 +1 \\
& g = \frac{\langle x_u \wedge x_v, x_{vv} \rangle}{\lVert x_u \wedge x_v \rVert} = -\frac{u^2}{\sqrt{1 + 2u^2}}
\end{align*}
and then $k_n (t) = - \frac1{2 \sqrt 3}$ everywhere.

I have now to see if the curve is geodesic, that is, I need to verify that $\alpha''$ is normal to the surface. First of all, I observe that $\alpha''(t) = x_{vv}(1, t) = (-\cos t, -\sin t, 0)$. Now

\begin{align*}
& \langle \alpha''(t), x_u(u(t), v(t)) \rangle = \langle x_{vv}(1, t), x_u(1, t) \rangle = -1 \\
& \langle \alpha''(t), x_v(u(t), v(t)) \rangle = \langle x_{vv}(1, t), x_v(1, t) \rangle = 0
\end{align*}
and $\alpha$ is not geodesic.

Is all this correct?

Comment: At a quick skim your calculations and conclusions look plausible. What is the question...?

Comment: Is all this correct? Just that.